# Installing plugins in vim in cygwin

Tags: linux, vim, cygwin

I'm trying to use pathogen to install [dbext](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim). I've gone through the install process without issue. Here is my bundle folder:

[image]

The way I install the plugins is by doing a git clone:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/whatevervimscriptiwant
```

For dbext, I've added these lines to my vimrc:

```
let g:dbext_default_profile_mySQLServer = 'type=SQLSRV:integratedlogin=1:srvname=ertts01s:dbname=345ite'
let g:dbext_default_use_win32_filenames = 1
nnoremap <unique> <Leader>se <Plug>DBExecSQLUnderCursor
```

My `leader` key is **,** (comma).

When type a statement such as :

```
select * from mytable
```

and running: `,se` on it, it just puts me into insert mode. The first two characters (`,s`) are accepted, meaning they appear in the lower right corner of vim, but as soon as I press the last character (`e`) it goes into insert mode.

**What am I doing wrong? How do I make sure that my plugins, especially dbext is installed properly?**